# Is there a way to set the width of a GridViewColumn to Auto?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, gridviewcolumn

Somewhere in code I have to set the width of a `GridViewColumn` to 0, and in another place I want to set it to `"Auto"` just like in the xaml, instead of reinventing what the xaml is doing when using `"Auto"`.

Any ideas on how to do this in code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/wpf/thread/5c0e3649-dda4-4242-b14e-e508abae1e42).

```
col.Width = Double.NaN;
```

That's actually the default value, so if you don't set Width, the column will be auto-sized by default.